# What are some javascript libraries for Membase

Tags: javascript, membase, couchbase

I'm looking for a clientside javascript interface to Membase. I'm particularly interested in reading off of the tap streams.

I use python scripts on the server to fill data buckets with stats such as transfer rates. My goal is to be able to plot these stats, among other real-time tasks, in a browser.

**use case**:
 I have a QOS device which is monitoring the signal quality of line cards. These line cards are encoders and decoders, among others, for a VOIP network. I want to dump information such as transfer rates, errors, and other rapidly changing data of the signals into membase. I'm going to plot representations of this "live" data with libs such as processing.js, raphaels.js

However, I need to get the data out of Membase first. The idea hear is *similar* to long-polling for changes on a Couchdb database (or any of you other favorite nosql solutions).

Anyone have recommendations?

Comment: I'm curious, what are you going to plot with the tap stream?

Comment: @mikewied Ok, I have a QOS device which is monitoring the signal quality of line cards. These line cards are encoders and decoders, among others, for a VOIP network. I want to dump information such as transfer rates, errors, and other rapidly changing data of the signals into membase. I'm going to plot representations of this "live" data with libs such as processing.js, raphaels.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the nicest things about Membase (and the upcoming Couchbase Server) is the protocol-level compatibility with memcached.  Thus, any memcached library will work out-of-the-box with our products.  A quick Google search came up with: http://code.google.com/p/jsmemcached-client/ but there were others as well...

Comment: thats the conclusion I've been converging on... that memchached libs work with membase. Maybe thats why there aren't "Membase" solutions, Those who know just use memchached libs. The node.js community obviously likes memchached, so Ive had some luck finding examples there. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no Membase or memcached client libraries written in Javascript, but I may be wrong. Couchbase, the company that develops and supports Membase, currently offers clients that support the tap interface for the Java, C/C++, and python languages. The python client actually ships with Membase, but it's really meant to be more of an example then something that is recommended for use in a production setting. The Java and C/C++ clients are the most well tested an bug free. Outside of the clients that Couchbase maintains I have seen one for Ruby, but have never used it so I'm not sure how reliable it is.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks mike. I've been digging through the python client, since thats what Im using server-side. you're right about it being an example, but thats plenty enough.